# Play Song in iTunes w/o Deselecting Highlighted Songs

Tags: itunes, music

I'm trimming my iTunes library, so I have multiple songs selected/highlighted which I want to review. Is there a way to play a song without accidentally deselecting the other highlighted ones?

---

Also, is there any way to stop iTunes automatically jumping to whatever track just started playing?

Answer (score 1):

One thing you can do is right clicking and click "Play next", going to the up next bar on the top, and clicking on the song you want to play and clearing the other selected song.

As to stopping iTunes from jumping to whatever track you just pressed, right click and choose "Play next" or "Add to Up Next" to put it in queue.

Answer (score 0):

You basically just want a way to keep songs in a list that you can go through and choose which ones you want to delete. There are two options that are much better than highlighting (iTunes 12.5.4):

1. Add songs to Up Next (three bulleted lines next to name of track now playing), *which is basically a playlist that will play automatically*, by right clicking on a song and clicking "Play Next" to play next or "Play Later" to put it at the bottom of the list. As you're listening you can choose what you want to delete by finding that song in your library and deleting it.
2. Or you could just create a new playlist such as "Delete?" and add songs to it and review them at your leisure (even on your iPhone) etc. and then delete from playlist after deciding to keep them, and then delete the remaining songs from your library if you decide to delete.

I don't believe there is a way to play a song without iTunes jumping to that track.